# No active connections found! Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: networking

I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, and that was working fine for days. Then I responded to a notification that there were software updates for 47 packages. I ran Software Update and the next time I rebooted, I no longer had network access!

I plugged in an external USB drive with CentOS 5 Live CD on it and the Dell hardware works correctly, both seeing networks and accessing the internet from CentOS.

PC: Dell GX-260

Running lshw under Ubuntu 11.10 shows that it finds:

description: Ethernet interface

product: Intel 82540OEM Gigabit Ethernet Controller

vendor: Intel Corporation

Please help me resolve my Ubuntu networking issue(s). This PC has been offline for days!

Thank you in advance for any and all help, guys and gals!

JohnE1

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This information covers the "driver em" needed for your specific Intel 82540OEM Gigabit Ethernet Controller

[Man Pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man4/em.4freebsd.html)

DESCRIPTION

The em driver provides support for PCI Gigabit Ethernet adapters based on
     the Intel 82540, 82541ER, 82541PI, 82542, 82543, 82544, 82545, 82546,
     82546EB, 82546GB, 82547, 82571, 81572, 82573, and 82574 Ethernet
     controller chips.

The driver supports Transmit/Receive checksum offload
     and Jumbo Frames on all but 82542-based adapters.  Furthermore it
     supports TCP segmentation offload (TSO) on all adapters but those based
     on the 82543, 82544 and 82547 controller chips.  The identification LEDs
     of the adapters supported by the em driver can be controlled via the
     led(4) API for localization purposes.

For further hardware information,
     see the README included with the driver.
[Driver page](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-006120.htm)